# NEST 2.0 ElasticSearch2 and .NET C# WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest

I have a .NET WebAPI and I recently moved to NEST2 and ElasticSearch2.

Before porting the code I had:

```
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<IConnectionSettingsValues>(),
            new OptionalParameter<IConnection>(),
            new OptionalParameter<INestSerializer>(),
            new OptionalParameter<ITransport>()));
```

to inject NEST into my WebAPI

Unfortunately the namespace

using Elasticsearch.Net.Connection;

doesn't exist anymore and I get three errors about `IConnection` `INestSerializer` `ITransport` not being found

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nest 2.x, namespaces have been simplified to put

- all types in assembly Elasticsearch.Net in namespace `Elasticsearch.Net`
- all types in assembly Nest in namespace `Nest`